# Ошибка в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Почему такой скрипт ничего не выводит?

```
document.write("Cats are fun. I like cats.".replace(/cats/gi."dogs"))
```

из-за ошибки `missing name after.operator` в начале "dogs"? Это пример из книжки вообще-то.
Что еще там должно быть?

Answer (score 1):

У вас стоит точка, а должна быть запятая.

Comment: а, да спасибо, просто в книге плохо пропечатано, не разглядела.